# Is it possible to use javax.xml.transform.Transformer with a xslt that contains some xalan:redirect?

Tags: java, xslt, xalan

I wrote a xslt for **xalan**, that works fine with the xalan cli (`org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process`).  The xslt uses the xalan extension `redirect` It does generate several xml files like expected.

Now I would like to do the transformation from a Java application.  I looked at the org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process source code, it is a bit complicated (1,000 lines of if/then/else).  I could not find documentation.  I am looking at the minimal code to call the transform and potentially set the output directory.

I tried something like:

```
    final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    InputStream in = null;
    InputStream xsl = null;
    try {
        in = inputFileStream;
        xsl = url.openStream();
        final TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory
                .newInstance();
        final Transformer transformer = tFactory
                .newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsl));
        transformer.transform(new StreamSource(in), new StreamResult(out));
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Activator.logErrorMessage(NLS.bind(
                Messages.Import_XSLT_TRANSFORMATION_FAILED, t.toString()));
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(xsl);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(out);
    }
```

It works fine for a simple xslt (i.e. without the redirect extension).  If I use a xslt with the redirect extension I get the regular output `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` but no other output files (like I got when using `org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process`).

What is the minimal call/API to use to transform using a xslt with redirect extension, and knowing where all the output files will end up ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the code was working fine.  It is just that I was not providing a full path to the `redirect:write file=""` and so I missed the fact that the output files were actually written.

I passed a parameter from the java to the xslt:

```
final Transformer transformer = templates.newTransformer();
transformer.setParameter("containerFullPath", containerFullPath);
transformer.transform(new StreamSource(in), new StreamResult(out));
```

And added the following line in the xslt:

```
<xsl:param name="containerFullPath"/> <!-- at the root of the xslt -->
...
    <redirect:write  file="{$containerFullPath}/{$modelName}-{@name}.bpmn">
...
```

Now, I can see the output files where they are supposed to be.